# VMware - Host two VPS with same IP

Tags: networking, tcp

I have:

- 1 Dedicated server, Windows server 2008.
- 2 Virtual machines inside the server. (VMware, Windows too)
- 1 example IP address: (0.0.0.1)
- 1 example IP address: (0.0.0.2)

I need:

- 1 Dedicated server with IP: (0.0.0.1) to host HTTP
- 2 Virtual servers both with IP: (0.0.0.2), one for HTTP, and the next one for FTP

[image: My Problem]

Is this even possible ? Please explain how it can be done on my VMware (workstation 9), because it's actually harder than it looks if you consider the port forwading of the two vps, and if you use only (0.0.0.1) on the host machine.

Comment: You're really running VMware...Workstation...on Server 2008? You used to have 2008 R2 SP1...

Comment: @MichaelHampton Sorry I don't get what you mean, can you explain ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. And it is not complicated - this is beginner admin stuff.

Your firewall (running on the dedicated server or better in front of it - and that can be a cheap 40 USD mikrotik 750) can forward incoming ports to different machines based on port numbers. Simple like that.

Now, FTP is more complex (it is not ONLY port 21) but any decent firewall can handle that just be telling it the forward is for a FTP port.

And I would really not put that onto the dedicated machine - use either a device, or a third vm.

Now, windows can NOT do it out of the box - though ARR (Application Request Routing) can do the fowarding of the HTTP side (not sure about FTP). But any decent linux or any decent firewall just can do it.

And seriously, get a decent hypervisor. No reason not to use Hyper-V when you run windows anyway on the host.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is, all of this is running on one single physical machine so i don't see how a physical firewall can help in this situation, it's more of a vmware configuration problem I think. I have never used Hyper-V but i'll give it a try today

Comment: Well, install a virtual firewall. I have a similar setup - a virtual firewall helps. And no, it is NOT a hypervisor problem. Hypervisors are not firewalls. They are not supposed to magically do firewall work.

Comment: After reading your post at least 10 times, I think I finally get what you were saying. The "third vm" did it for me! With no firewall or any special software, I created a third vm, made it bridged to the physical network card of the host, so it acts as a gateway for the other 2 vps that are connected in private. Anyways, complicated stuff.. Thank you

Comment: If you think that is complicated you should see some of the other stuff we do. Wait until you ahve a dozen or two vlanÄs with partially overlapping IP addresses and must find a way for them to work with each other.